# Bootstrap Repeat Columns beneath each using parent width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to create a page using bootstrap. Now what I am trying to achieve is having a search bar to the right with width of 3/12 and items to the left with width 1/12 and 8/12 and 9/12 as shown in the image attached.

[image]

now the problem is one the search bar to the right (col3) finish the elements float next to the ones above them. I am not using a col9 and inserting everything inside it because I would deviate from the design size wise because of columns.

EDIT:

this is the code

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:50px;background:blue"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="height:100px;background:yellow"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-1" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:50px;background:blue"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="height:100px;background:yellow"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-1" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:50px;background:blue"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="height:100px;background:yellow"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right" style="height:250px;background:green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another Image with the current results

[image]

Comment: Being able to see your custom CSS and HTML would be of help, a picture alone doesn't help to see what you have done to cause this.

Comment: You're asking an HTML/CSS question.  You should be including HTML & CSS in your question to correctly reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also clarify more on where you're wanting the `col3` you have crossed out.  The wording in your question isn't clear.

Comment: My apologies, did not include the html since it is quite simple bootstrap, but you're right

Comment: It is quite simple bootstrap, but i see straight away you are missing divs per row.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ackLdyr3/4/

Comment: The thing is I cannot add row since than I would need to ratio the columns. If I use row I cannot use 1/12 for the first small div, since it would become 0.75/12 in the new row which is in a div 9/12. I hope I am clear in what I am saying

Comment: Would making a wrapping row of 9, with 2, 10 and 12 not work? i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/ackLdyr3/5/

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid since it would deviate from the design. Thanks for your answer though.